# Click on .a and skip to certain part of site

Tags: jquery

I'm looking for a jquery or whatever you need to do this: When you click on a certain category, '#{Category}' is added to the url and it skips to the wished part. How does this work?

Comment: Go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) and navigate to the **Create a Bookmark** portion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are Anchors.

You need to define somewhere in your page an item with a specific ID, for example

`<h2 id="my_custom_id">This is a title but it can be anything else</h2>`

then you make a link like this:

`<a href="#my_custom_id">Anchor example</a>`